# How to build feature to share app in flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, app-store-connect

I am looking for solution to share app through the flutter application , just like inviting others to download the app. how should i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [share package](https://pub.dev/packages/share) to share a link to your app. There are many websites that can generate a link to your app that works on iOS and Android, for example: [onelink.to](https://onelink.to)

Comment: But, can two links be configured in one link? I mean a link is shared on whatsapp, twitter or facebook, i want if the link is opened in android platform the user should be directed to playstore and if the link is opened in iOS it should go to the Appstore.

Comment: @FrankRussell This can be done with [onelink.to](https://onelink.to). It will redirect the user to the correct app store depending on their device